# Passportjs - How do I request a user's image using the Google strategy?

Tags: node.js, google-api, passport.js

How can I configure my Google API access to request a user's image while authenticating? Currently 'profile' only contains the following properties after a user has successfull authenticated:

profile.identifier : (string)

profile.displayName : (string)

profile.emails : (object)

name :(object)

Isn't it possible to request the user's account image? Here is my current Passport/Google strategy configuration:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET, 
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    console.log('identifier ' + identifier)
    for(var p in profile){
        console.log(p + ' : ' + profile[p])
        if(p === 'name'){
            for(var n in profile[p]){
                console.log(n + ' : ' + profile[p][n])
            }
        }
    }
  }
));
```

You can see that I am inspecting the profile to see what information is returned. I assume this needs to be configure somehow in my Google Api console. Is this a Google+ api feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The profile object returned by passport, only maps a few fields:

```
profile.id = json.id;
profile.displayName = json.name;
profile.name = { familyName: json.family_name,
                 givenName: json.given_name };
profile.emails = [{ value: json.email }];
```

But it does give you back a `_json` property that contains more information:

Try:

```
var picture = profile._json['picture'];
```

Comment: That's interesting because I have seen other examples of people getting information from a profile._json property. But that property does not seem to exist on my profile obj. profile._json === 'undefined'

Comment: You are using Google OpenID strategy. Try the OAuth2 one instead. That returns the _json property I was mentioning in my answer: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth

Comment: Great. OAuth2 gives me what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These days, the following two fields return the user's image:

```
var picture = '';

picture = profile._json.image.url;
picture = profile.photos[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
profile.photos[0].value
```

This is what it returned

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgxnR-ia_f8_hJpUNdD4CoL9IM
```